# Create a pdf file in flutter with some attributes like name, author, date etc

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to create a pdf file with some attributes like name, author, date, etc so that whenever I want to access details I can easily access them using file attributes.

Comment: did you try this packages https://pub.dev/packages/pdf ?

Comment: i think this only creates a pdf file...